# How to cache all directories of my repository using Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a problem, how could I cache multiple directories in gitlab ci? When Gitlab-runner download the repository, inside I have like 10 folders (diferent projects), some project depeneds of another, so I would like do it available for the next jobs.

I thought do it something like that, without specifying all folders manually

```
cache:
  paths:
    - "./"
```

Could be work this or I need something else?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is to cache all the untracked files and directories of the repository, yo can use `untracked:true`

```
job_name:
  script: test
  cache:
    untracked: true
```

You can also combine this with the `path` keyword like this:

```
rspec:
  script: test
  cache:
    untracked: true
    paths:
      - your_path/
```

You may use wildcards for the paths too like `your_path/*.jar` to take every `.jar` file in the directory.

I point you to the official GitLab documentation for more info: [GitLab-CI documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cacheuntracked)

Comment: Thank you @zarzanduil, finally I used the first method you expose

Comment: According to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/?query=untracked#cachepaths "The cache:paths keyword includes files even if they are untracked or in your .gitignore file."